# App code (result) is not updated but new docker image and container are created while using Github Actions with EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

Problem: My Github actions is successful and new docker images and containers are created as I can see it using `docker ps -a` but the Code output from the app is old.

This is my dummy `main.py` code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "Show This"}
```

and my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app 
COPY ./ /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

and my `.github/workflows/deploy.yml` looks like:

```
name: Deploy to AWS EC2

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy to AWS EC2
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup SSH
      run: |
        mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
        echo "${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        ssh-keyscan "${{ secrets.EC2_PUBLIC_DNS }}" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

    - name: SSH and Deploy
      run: |
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@"${{secrets.EC2_PUBLIC_DNS}}" << EOF
          git clone https://${{ secrets.REPO_CLONE_ACCESS_TOKEN }}@github.com/mahesh-jackett/actions.git
          cd actions
          docker stop fastapi_container
          docker rm fastapi_container
          docker build -t fastapi_image .
          docker run -d --name fastapi_container -p 8000:8000 fastapi_image
        EOF
```

But the result for the app is `{"Hello": "World"}` and even top of that, the `DockerFile` is add as can be seen from the screenshot Line 77.

[image]

Comment: IIUC, you are updating your code but the new code is not being reflected i.e. neither in the docker image and subsequently nor in the final running container, right?

Comment: @Azeem Oh okay. So I need to `rm -rf actions` first and then use `git clone`?

Comment: Yes, seems like it. You need to verify its logs. Without removing it first, `git clone` must be failing with proper error log.

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action. You might want to use it.